# pd.read_csv not able to load client review data

Tags: pandas

I am using `pd.read_csv` with `chunkszie` to load `1.6GB` text file into `dataframe` format. 
A typical group of data is like the below:

```
beer/name: Sausa Weizen

review/aroma: 2

review/palate: 1.5

review/text: A lot of foam. But a lot.  In the smell some banana, and then lactic and tart. Not a good start.   Quite dark orange in color, with a lively carbonation (now visible, under the foam).    Again tending to lactic sourness.   Same for the taste. With some yeast and banana.
```

And here is my code:

```
    chunksize = 10**5
    TextFileReader = pd.read_csv('beerreview.txt', error_bad_lines=False, 
    chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True)
    beerdata = pd.concat(TextFileReader, ignore_index=True)
```

However, after finishing running the code, I get every field but the `'review/text'`. May I know why it is so?

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, a few lines from your CSV and the code you are running.

Comment: Could you post (copy/paste) some actual lines from the beerreview.txt?

Comment: thanks all for looking into this. thank you @kj007 for editing my post, i am very new to python and stackoverflow. I have figured out the issue is with the comas in the review/text line, i resolve it by set delimiter to \n.